# Blocks floating outside their Container Div

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem on my webpage: [image]

As you can see the inner div items are floating outside their container. I saw a few threads on here about using

```
display:inline-block;
```

and I tried a few variations but no luck. If I set display to inline-block on both my #container and my #itemWrapper then my margins get lost on my center panel, but if I set display to inline-block on my gallery then nothing happens, a bit confused here.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <section id="header">

            <div class="logo">

                <h1 id="logoText">Dope Clothing</h1>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="nav">

            <div id="nav-wrapper">

                <ul id="nav-list">

                    <li id="nav-home"><a href="">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav-brands"><a href="">Brands</a>
                        <ul id="brands-list">
                            <li><a href="">Brand01</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">Brand02</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">Brand03</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">Brand04</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">Brand05</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav-about"><a href="">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="main">

            <div id="content">

                <div id="gallery">

                    <div class="itemWrapper">
                        <div class="pictureWrapper"><img class="itemPicture" src="Images/Clothing/green.png"/></div>
                        <div class="itemDetails">
                            <div class="itemTitle">Naartjie Fresh</div>
                            <div class="itemPrice">R150.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemWrapper">
                        <div class="pictureWrapper"><img class="itemPicture" src="Images/Clothing/green.png"/></div>
                        <div class="itemDetails">
                            <div class="itemTitle">Naartjie Fresh</div>
                            <div class="itemPrice">R150.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemWrapper">
                        <div class="pictureWrapper"><img class="itemPicture" src="Images/Clothing/green.png"/></div>
                        <div class="itemDetails">
                            <div class="itemTitle">Naartjie Fresh</div>
                            <div class="itemPrice">R150.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemWrapper">
                        <div class="pictureWrapper"><img class="itemPicture" src="Images/Clothing/green.png"/></div>
                        <div class="itemDetails">
                            <div class="itemTitle">Naartjie Fresh</div>
                            <div class="itemPrice">R150.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemWrapper">
                        <div class="pictureWrapper"><img class="itemPicture" src="Images/Clothing/green.png"/></div>
                        <div class="itemDetails">
                            <div class="itemTitle">Naartjie Fresh</div>
                            <div class="itemPrice">R150.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemWrapper">
                        <div class="pictureWrapper"><img class="itemPicture" src="Images/Clothing/green.png"/></div>
                        <div class="itemDetails">
                            <div class="itemTitle">Naartjie Fresh</div>
                            <div class="itemPrice">R150.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <aside id="share-wrapper">
                <div id="sharebutton">></div>

                <div id="share">
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="facebook-share">f</div></div>
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="twitter-share">t</div></div>
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="google-share">g</div></div>
                    <div class="share-box"><div class="insta-share">i</div></div>
                </div>

            </aside>

        </section>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

#header,
#footer {
    background-color: #000000;
}

#header { padding-top:50px; padding-left:50px; padding-bottom:20px; }

#logoText { color:#FFFFFF; font-size:54px; }

#nav-wrapper { padding-top:40px; text-align:center; }

#nav-list { display:inline; }

#nav-list li { display:inline-block; margin-right:30px; padding-right:30px; }

#nav-list li a { text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size:20px; }

#nav-list li a:hover { color:#CECECE;}

#nav-home, #nav-brands, #nav-about { border-right:thin solid black; }

#nav-brands { position:relative; }

#nav-list li:hover ul { display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }

#brands-list { padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: -35px; width: 120px; box-shadow: none; display: none; opacity: 0;
               visibility: hidden; -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s; -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s; -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
               -o-transition: opacity 0.2s; -transition: opacity 0.2s; border:thin solid #000000; border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
               border-top:0px;
}

#brands-list li { display: block; margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; text-align:center; border-bottom:thin solid #CECECE;

}

#brands-list li:hover {}

#brands-list li:last-child { border-bottom:0px; }

#content {
    width:1080px;
    margin:10px auto;
    border-left:thin groove #333;
}

#share-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:180px;
}

#share {
    border:thin solid #333;
    border-left:0px;
    border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    width:30px;
    padding:0px 5px;
    height:170px;
}

#sharebutton {
    color:#eeeeee;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
}

.share-box,
.share-box img {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}

.facebook-share,
.twitter-share,
.google-share,
.insta-share { width: 100%; height: 100%; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; color:#333; border:thin solid #333; border-radius:15px; margin:10px 0px; background-color:#eee;}

.facebook-share:hover,
.twitter-share:hover,
.google-share:hover,
.insta-share:hover { background-color:#333; color:#eee; }

.share-box img {

}

#content { margin:0px auto; max-width:1080px; border:0px;}

.itemWrapper { max-width:280px; float:left; margin:10px;}

.itemPicture { max-height:280px; max-width:280px; }

.itemTitle { text-align: center; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; }

.itemPrice { text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; }

#footer { color:#cecece; padding:20px;}

#facebook { width:20px; height:20px; text-align:center; border-radius:10px; border:1px solid #cecece; }
```

EDIT :::::::::::

Okay so adding display:inline-block to my #gallery div without the inline-block on the item-wrapper seemed to do the trick, however I still cant seem to get the share box to appear on the side ??

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank div inside the layer where items have float values and apply:

```
clear: both;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either clear your floats or contain them within a block formatting context.

If you add the following CSS rule:

```
#gallery {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

you will trigger a new block formatting context and the edges of your floated elements will not interfere/interfact with the rest of your layout elements.

Note: You can also use `overflow: hidden`, both work, I just prefer the `auto` value.

Comment: Do I need to clear the floats as well as set the displat to inline-block ?

Comment: You only need to clear floats or use `overflow: {auto|hidden}` if you are floating elements.  Inline-blocks do not need to be cleared since they are part of the regular content flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `overflow:hidden;` to `<div id="content">`